# Facebook iOS SDK--closeAndClearTokenInformation not removing access token

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, token, expired-sessions

In my iOS app I am logged into Facebook via iOS Settings.

If the user removes the app from Facebook or changes his password, the token is expired and invalid.

My app detects this and calls:

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

then asks the user to login again.

However, after the user is logs in, the `authToken` provided by the `FBSession` object is the SAME expired token.

This is a problem because I use the auth token server side to authenticate certain requests.

Right now it seems the only way to remedy this is to remove the FB account from the iOS settings and recreate the FB Account.

Am I wrong in my assumption that `closeAndClearTokenInformation` is supposed to reset everything? Is there another method I should use?